# Google App Script - How to set a spreadsheet file value from a string formatted through just one array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-api

I am a beginner of programming.
The code snippet below in my GS project works very well.

```
var nextRow = Sheet_current.getLastRow() + 1; // Line 1
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var temp = new Array(); //Line 3
temp = str.split(",");
var target = new Array(); //Line 5
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    target.push([temp[i]]);
}
Sheet_current.getRange(Sheet_current.getLastRow() + 1, 1, target.length, target[0].length).setValues(target); //Line 9
```

Results in my spreadsheet file when running the above code:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeeRZ.png)

I use a string as input, then convert it into a temporary array (Line 3).

I continue to declare a target array, to pass the values of the temporary array to the target array. (Lines 5 to 7)

Finally, I use the target array to dump the values into my spreadsheet (vertically, each word in the target array corresponds to a row in the spreadsheet file) (Line 9).

Can someone help me how to optimize the code that only through just one array.

Sincerely thank.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to provide result on differents row and starting from the first column, you can use the [appendRow() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)). Here is a example of use in your case:

```
function myFunction() {
  var Sheet_current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var nextRow = Sheet_current.getLastRow() + 1; // Line 1
  var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
  var target = new Array(); //Line 3
  target = str.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    Sheet_current.appendRow([target[i]]);
  }
}
```

Or you can just made the modification you want on your first array to keep your structure like :

```
function myFunction2(){
  var Sheet_current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var nextRow = Sheet_current.getLastRow() + 1;
  var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
  var temp = new Array();
  temp = str.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = [temp[i]]; // To convert your Array[] on Array[][]
  }
  Sheet_current.getRange(Sheet_current.getLastRow() + 1, 1, temp.length, temp[0].length).setValues(temp); 
}
```

But I don't recommend this method, since it's okay for little program, but can be tricky for larger one.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback - Pierre-Marie Richard.

I replaced your code in my GS project.

Almost the problem with just using one of my original arrays has been resolved, but when I recheck the logs for execution, I see that the <getRange> method then <setValues> executes in the interval of 0.3 - 0.5 seconds, while the <appendRow> method is between 0.7 - 0.9 seconds.

I just ran the code from your <myFunction>. While writing back to you, got more from you <myFunction2>. Now I will run the second code snippet from you.

Again, I am really grateful to you. Thanks.

Comment: The appendRow() method is a big longer but as a advantage of being atomic, which could be useful.

Comment: Very nice, your second code runs very well in my project. My problem was solved completely. Maybe I will consider using my original code or your second code snippet, because these two scripts have nearly the same execution time when I try to enter a string containing 1000 elements. Again, I am very grateful to you, thank you very much.